# How can I create a 'debian/control' file that differs based on Ubuntu release?

Tags: python, packaging, deb

I have great deal of source code that we maintain, producing many different Ubuntu packages. All of these packages need to build on Ubuntu LTS releases from [Ubuntu 8.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_8.04_LTS_(Hardy_Heron)) (Hardy Heron) forward. (Yes, I know these are old and unsupported. These are for space-bound systems, so updating to a new release is not possible. Yet I still have to maintain the software on them, while updating for new releases.)

I am trying to get the entire code base up and running on [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr). I have discovered much to my dismay that the packaging of Python code has changed completely. As of Trusty, python-support and python-central have disappeared and [dh_python2 is what you have to use](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/TransitionToDHPython2?action=show&redirect=Python%2FPyCentral2DhPython2).

My problem is how to craft a working `debian/control` file. The Build-Depends: for versions up to and including [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) needs to include `python-central`, while for 14.04 and forward it must include `dh_python2`. I have found no provision for conditional text in the control file. I've tried find a way around this, but so far nothing works.

How can this be done?

I have an extensive buildbot system up and running that compiles on numerous Ubuntu versions, CentOS versions, and some OS X versions. Splitting into branched packages for different versions would break that. So I'm looking for a solution that works on a single source tree. I'm trying to find a hook early on that I could use in dpkg-buildpackage to set things up per-version, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Have you read https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html?

Comment: When trying to use "|" for alternatives, I get:

    dpkg-source: warning: can't parse dependency python-central | dh_python2
    dpkg-source: error: error occurred while parsing Build-Depends

Comment: I use the latest version for each release. 08.04, 10.04, 12.04 and 14.04. So they will all be different. And I need to find a way to build from the same source in each of these. And imminently, 16.04.

Comment: I can, and I'm trying to find a good spot to do this. I create one tarball that is used by all the different source package builds, so the magic has to happen somewhere in the source build. If I could figure out what "dh" rule queries the environment variables, and then override that to add some pre-processing, it should work. The environment variable setting appears to not reference the control file.

Comment: Unfortunately, `dh` starts its work well after the control file has been read. You can't affect parsing of `control` with `dh`. Consider replacing `dpkg-buildpackage` with a script.

Comment: @JimWright Could you please paste full source part of d/control to the question? As I said below, the `|` for alternatives is just fine, I am guessing there's some other error that prevents dpkg-source to fail.

Comment: @JimWright And immediately after that I noticed that you are trying to depend on "filename" and not package name as `dh_python2` is included in `dh-python` package. See comment in my answer below for longer version.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use alternative packages in the `Build-Depends` field, f.e. `Build-Depends: dh-python | python-central, [...]`.  That has several quirks, the first dependency that satisfy the dependency solver will get picked.  You can also use versioned Build-Depends (f.e. if you know that some earlier versions of packages were incomplete), i.e. `Build-Depends: dh-python (>= <correct_version) | python-central`.

The more complicated way if you need to Depend on package that doesn't exists in earlier (or later release) is to add `base-files (<< <version>) | real-package` as a dependency instead of just `real-package` and tune the `<version>` to match the version in the next release.  If you need a package on older system, but not on new, you would use `base-file (>= <version>) | real-package` and use `<version>` from Ubuntu release where you don't need the `real-package`.

For example for backporting `apache2` for Ubuntu 12.04 I have changed `libnghttp2-dev` to `base-files (<< 7.2~) | libnghttp2-dev`.

I will add `d/rules` snippet from my MySQL-5.6 backport:

```
DPKG_VENDOR          ?= $(shell dpkg-vendor --query Vendor | tr [A-Z] [a-z])
DEB_DISTRIBUTION     = $(shell dpkg-parsechangelog | sed -ne 's/^Distribution: //p')

ENABLE_SYSTEMD = yes

ifeq (ubuntu,$(DPKG_VENDOR))
  ifeq ($(DEB_DISTRIBUTION),$(filter $(DEB_DISTRIBUTION),precise))
    $(warning Disabling systemd on $(DPKG_VENDOR) $(DEB_DISTRIBUTION))
    ENABLE_SYSTEMD = no
  endif
endif

[...]
%:
ifeq (yes,$(ENABLE_SYSTEMD))
        dh $@ --parallel --with systemd
else
        dh $@ --parallel
endif
```

and `d/control` has

```
Build-Depends: [...], dh-systemd (>= 1.5) | base-files (<< 7.2ubuntu5~)
```

Comment: OP has to work with too old a dpkg, it seems.  `|` itself apparently doesn't work.

Comment: @muru dpkg supports alternative dependencies `|` as far as my memory goes. So I am guessing this might be some other problem and dpkg confirms that it supported `|` even before my engagement with Debian: `a.out control file says Pre-Depends: libc4 | libc.` <-- this is from 1996.

Comment: Interesting. OP edited out the error message, but it's available in the revisions: http://askubuntu.com/revisions/760853/3 Can you tell what's wrong? Perhaps we should ask OP to post the `debian/control` file they tried.

Comment: @muru @JimWright I see, the package name is not dh_python2 as Debian package names cannot contain underscore. I should have noticed on the first look, but hey it's Sunday afternoon :). The correct package name is `dh-python`, so it should be: `Build-Depends: python-central | dh-python`.

Comment: Yes, I had incorrect package name. I've corrected that. There is a possibility that the errors related to having an underscore in the name. In any case, I solved the problem following the helpful advice from @muru. I implemented a step in buildbot prior to calling dpkg-buildpackage which adjusts the source so that it can build on any system.

Comment: @JimWright That's not "possibility", but that's true. Package names cannot contain underscore, as underscore is used as delimiter between package name and package version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script I came up with to allow the code to build on any release. In my case, I created a control.pre_trusty and control.post_precise file, and a rules.pre_trusty and rules.post_precise.

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# Do magic to allow building on different Ubuntu releases. This script is
# called by buildbot on the different systems prior to dpkg-buildpackage. Do
# what is needed to accomodate different build step requirements as
# Ubuntu changes.
# "pre" and "post" are not inclusive. For example, *.pre_precise files
# apply to hardy and lucid, but not precise or anything after.

RELEASE=$(lsb_release --release --short | tr -d '.')
export LANG=C   # so "cp" doesn't use fancy quoting, which messes up web page

#######################################################################
### we need to run this from the debian directory
#######################################################################
if [ -d debian ] ; then cd debian ; fi
if [ -d "*/debian" ] ; then cd */debian ; fi

#######################################################################
### copy files that apply to previous releases
#######################################################################
cp_pre_lucid ()
{
    for i in *.pre_lucid ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .pre_lucid) ; fi
    done
}

cp_pre_precise ()
{
    for i in *.pre_precise ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .pre_precise) ; fi
    done
}

cp_pre_trusty ()
{
    for i in *.pre_trusty ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .pre_trusty) ; fi
    done
}

cp_pre_xenial ()
{
    for i in *.pre_xenial ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .pre_xenial) ; fi
    done
}

#######################################################################
### copy files that apply to subsequent releases
#######################################################################
cp_post_hardy ()
{
    for i in *.post_hardy ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .post_hardy) ; fi
    done
}

cp_post_lucid ()
{
    for i in *.post_lucid ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .post_lucid) ; fi
    done
}

cp_post_precise ()
{
    for i in *.post_precise ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .post_precise) ; fi
    done
}

cp_post_trusty ()
{
    for i in *.post_trusty ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .post_trusty) ; fi
    done
}

#######################################################################
### process files for each release
#######################################################################
if [ "$RELEASE" -eq 804 ] ; then
    echo "Setup for Hardy 08.04"
    for i in *.hardy ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .hardy) ; fi
    done
    cp_pre_lucid
    cp_pre_precise
    cp_pre_trusty
    cp_pre_xenial

elif [ "$RELEASE" -eq 1004 ] ; then
    echo "Setup for Lucid 10.04"
    cp_post_hardy
    for i in *.lucid ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .lucid) ; fi
    done
    cp_pre_precise
    cp_pre_trusty
    cp_pre_xenial

elif [ "$RELEASE" -eq 1204 ] ; then
    echo "Setup for Precise 12.04"
    cp_post_hardy
    cp_post_lucid
    for i in *.precise ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .precise) ; fi
    done
    cp_pre_trusty
    cp_pre_xenial

elif [ "$RELEASE" -eq 1404 ] ; then
    echo "Setup for Trusty 14.04"
    cp_post_hardy
    cp_post_lucid
    cp_post_precise
    for i in *.trusty ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .trusty) ; fi
    done
    cp_pre_xenial

elif [ "$RELEASE" -eq 1604 ] ; then
    cp_post_hardy
    cp_post_lucid
    cp_post_precise
    cp_post_trusty
    echo "Setup for Xenial 16.04"
    for i in *.xenial ; do
        if [ -f $i ] ; then cp -v -p $i $(basename $i .xenial) ; fi
    done

else
    echo "ERROR: unknown Ubuntu LTS release number '$RELEASE'"
    exit 1
fi
```